# What are these notifications which only appear on the lock screen?

Tags: lock-screen, notification

Sometimes when I lock my screen there are notifications at the bottom

[image]

When I click them nothing happens. When I unlock the screen I can't see them anywhere.

What is causing these notifications? How am I supposed to interact with them? And can I turn them off?

Comment: After logging in, you may find (some of) them in the notification area, which pops up when you click on the date/time in the task bar.

Answer (score 1):

If the notifications are of no value, they can be disabled with a single toggle. Assuming you're using 22.04, here's how you do it:

1. Open the "Settings" application
2. Choose "Notifications" from the side
3. Toggle the "Lock Screen Notifications" option off:
   [image: 22.04 - Notifications]
4. Enjoy a notification-free lock screen

Comment: Thank you. Do you know why not all notifications (in the notification area when unlocked) are appearing on the lock screen?